# Solve $f(4x-5)$ and $f(-7)$ when $f(2x+1) = x^2 +4x +2$

Tags: functions

I know that if $f(x)= ...$ and when $f(-7)$ given, I just have to plug it in and solve. But for this it had given $f(2x+1)$, so can anybody guide me to this equation?

Comment: Did you try to substitute $x$ by, say, $ax+b$ ?

Comment: what is sth? sounds like gibberish.

Comment: @user140776 An abbreviation for "something" I suspect.

Answer (score 4):

You can solve $2c+1=-7$ and then $f(-7)=c^2+4c+2$ can be found. Try the other in a similar way.

Answer (score 1):

The first example is easy. If you write $2x+1 = -7$, than $x=-4$, and therefore:
$$f(-7)=f(2(-4)+1)=16-16+2 = 2$$

Now for the second one, change the variable, so that if $4x-5 = 2y+1$, we have $y = 2x - 3$, so that:

$$f(4x-5)=f(2y+1) = y^2+4y+2 = (2x - 3)^2+4(2x - 3) + 2$$